# JSpinner in array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jspinner

I have array JSpinners, but I can´t listening.

This one no working, because Java want final variable. When I change spin4[j] to spin4[0] <- it is working. But i need array with JSpinners. Help please.

```
 spin4[j].addChangeListener(
                                new ChangeListener(){
                                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                                Object o =spin4[j].getValue();
                                Number n = (Number) o;
                                pocatek = n.intValue();       
                                };
                            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Then either make the necessary variable final, or make a copy that is final. I'm guessing your variable of interest is `j`, and that `j` is a loop index which can't be declared final. If so, then create a final copy variable that copies j's value and is used inside of the inner class. For example, something like,...

```
for (int j = 0; j < spin4.length; j++) {
    final int innerJ = j;
    spin4[j] = new JSpinner(/* model here */); // ????? do you have or need this
    spin4[j].addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            Object o =spin4[innerJ].getValue();
            Number n = (Number) o;
            pocatek = n.intValue();       
        };
    });
}
```